# Can we look at only the voltage specification of a product?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, resistors, power-electronics, electromagnetism

[image]

I saw this specification in the product I wish to buy. Does that mean if I connect a 12V voltage supply from a battery, the current will actually be 5.8 A by default since the resistance of the device is constant? Is it true that we can just look at the voltage specification only and need not to care about measuring the current after connecting to the voltage supply?

Comment: Who says the device has a constant resistance?

Comment: The spec says the MAXIMUM current is 5.8 Amp.  Depending on the device, the normal current may be much less, and the current may vary depending on what the device is doing.  You need a supply that can deliver at least 5.8 amps.

Comment: I = V / load R  is dependent on load properties not just supply

Comment: I think OP might be talking about a Peltier thermoelectric cooler rather than a power supply, but it would have been useful for them to mention that. (In other words, the proposed duplicate question may or may not be accurate.)

Comment: You don't need to *measure* voltage or current.  As a developer it is essential to know, but users don't need them.

Comment: > Is it true that we can just look at the voltage specification only and need not to care about measuring the current after connecting to the voltage supply?   **not true**